# RangeSlider unexpeted attribute Bokeh

Tags: bokeh, rangeslider

I am trying to use the `RangeSlider` within my Bokeh-application, initializing the object as so

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import RangeSlider

#RangeSlider
slider = RangeSlider(title="OAS slider", start=0, end=1000, value=(0,2000), 
                     step=0.1)
```

When trying to compile the app I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'value' to RangeSlider, possible attributes are 
callback, callback_policy, callback_throttle, css_classes, disabled, end, 
height, js_callbacks, name, orientation, range, sizing_mode, start, step, 
tags, title or width
```

I could change the code to use `range` instead as so

```
#RangeSlider altered inputs
slider = RangeSlider(title="OAS slider", start=0, end=1000, range=(0,2000), 
                     step=0.1)
```

and it works.

However, as the example on the Bokeh-homepage found here

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/export_csv/main.py

used the `value` and works, I would be more eager to understand why I get the error message, rather than just changing to `range`... The example in the link also used the key word `format`, which obviously also generates the error above.

Could be a version issue. I am running Bokeh version 0.12.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version issue. The `RangeSlider` was actually mostly broken for a long time, until we switched to a different underlying slider library to implement it. But some changes were necessary to make the switch. The correct property for `0.12.7` and newer is `value` and I would recommend to use that version or later if you want too use `RangeSlider` especially (`0.12.4` is over a year old.)